# How does php obtain client certificates when opening an ssl socket from fsockopen()

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, openssl, client-certificates

I'm running a PHP client program on OS X 10.10 built in apache server. PHP (5.5) is configured with OpenSSL. When connecting to a server via a secure socket using `fsockopen()` how does the client obtain the certificates required for a secure connection since we are not providing them specifically ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you're not supplying any then it won't. If you were using fsockopen for SSL connections, you'd be using the appropriate [context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php).

Comment: @mario Thanks a lot for the clarification and the links are very helpful. How should I handle this? Should I remove this question?

Comment: No, just leave it. I'll make a cross-link (so it becomes either to find for others), since it also answers the topic.